# Mark TestNG test as passed

Tags: java, automation, testng

In my test scenario, if a certain flag is set, I need to skip the remaining steps. Due to the way the test suite functions, a simple if-else is not sufficient here. So I throw an exception and catch it in my implementation of `IHookable.run()` for some logging.

Now, even if I don't rethrow the exception after catching it, TestNG marks the test as failed. I have tried `Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().setStatus(ITestResult.SUCCESS);` and `Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().setThrowable(null);` in the catch block but nothing seems to prevent TestNG from marking the test as failed.

Any other ideas on how I can implement this scenario? Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own listener that will do this for you. I have written some thing that works(I dont know if this what you are exactly looking for).

My Listener :

```
public class MyResultListener implements ISuiteListener{

    @Override
    public void onStart(ISuite suite) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish(ISuite suite) {
    Map<String,ISuiteResult> resultMap = suite.getResults();
    for(Map.Entry<String, ISuiteResult> ent :resultMap.entrySet())
    {
       ISuiteResult res = ent.getValue();
       IResultMap failedTestMap = res.getTestContext().getFailedTests();
       IResultMap passTestMap = res.getTestContext().getPassedTests();
        for(ITestResult testResult :failedTestMap.getAllResults()){

        if(testResult.getThrowable().getClass().equals(new MyOwnException())){}

           System.out.println("My Own exception thrown");
            failedTestMap.removeResult(testResult);
            passTestMap.addResult(testResult, testResult.getMethod());
        }
        }

    }   
  }
```

This listener will be run after suite (It is just what i ahve done, You can implement other listeners also to get what you exactly need. This is just my version). Here, I will get the failed tests and see if the failed tests throw my custom exception. In that case I will remove that result from failed tests and add it to passed set.

My test class:

```
@Listeners(com.paypal.test.sample.testng.MyResultListener.class)
public class SampleTest {


    @Test
    public void test1(){

    Assert.assertTrue(true);

    }

    @Test
    public void test2() throws MyOwnException{

        throw new MyOwnException("Summa");

    }

}


This is how my results look:

PASSED: test1
FAILED: test2
com.paypal.test.sample.testng.MyOwnException: Summa
    at com.paypal.test.sample.testng.SampleTest.test2(SampleTest.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

My Own exception thrown

===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Answer (score 2):

Gosakas solution is great or else you can implement

```
 public interface ITestListener.
```

And override the method `onTestFailure(ITestResult result)` like it is done above. This will be called after every test failure. Something like this might work

```
        @Override
        onTestFailure(ITestResult result){
        if(result.getThrowable().getClass().equals(new MyOwnException())){
            result.setStatus(ITestResult.SUCCESS);
       }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

**If you need to skip a TestNG test, you should throw `SkipException` and that will mark the test as Skipped.**

Comment: It does mark the test as skipped but the suite gets marked as failed because some tests were skipped. I need to mark it as passed. Thanks for the suggestion! Any other idea?